# plot multiple data series from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, loops

I had a very ambitious project (for my novice level) to use on numpy array, where I load a series of data, and make different plots based on my needs - I have uploaded a slim version of my data file [input_data](http://pastebin.com/DyUnteN8) and wanted to make plots based on: F (where I would like to choose the desired F before looping), and each series will have the data from E column (e.g. A12 one data series, A23 another data series in the plot, etc) and on the X axis I would like to use the corresponding values in D.

so to summarize for a chosen value on column F I want to have 4 different data series (as the number of variables on column E) and the data should be reference (x-axis) on the value of column D (which is date)

I stumbled in the first step (although spend too much time) where I wanted to plot all data with F column identifier as one plot. 
Here is what I have up to now:

```
import os 
import numpy as np
N = 8 #different values on column F
M = 4 #different values on column E
dataset = open('array_data.txt').readlines()[1:]
data = np.genfromtxt(dataset)
my_array = data
day = len(my_array)/M/N # number of measurement sets - variation on column D
for i in range(0, len(my_array), N):
    plt.xlim(0, )
    plt.ylim(-1, 2)
    plt.plot(my_array[i, 0], my_array[i, 2], 'o')
    plt.hold(True)
plt.show()
```

this does nothing.... and I still have a long way to go..

Comment: `genfromtxt` expects a *filename* or a *file object*, not a list of strings.  Try `data = np.genfromtxt('array_data.txt', skip_header=1)`.  And try debugging one step at a time: make sure you have good data before you try to plot it.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for the hint; useful to know about skip header; the [1:] at the end of the previous line takes care of the header problem - I am able to load the data, but when I try that I get a single point as a plot

Comment: have you heard of [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)? it sounds like something you might want to use. you can load your data into a data frame and then plot it from there. if you give a sample of the data I can show you.

Comment: @Raufio yes, I actually used pands once - but basically I followed one example given to me and I just adjusted it to my data - so i am not experienced at all; if you see on the question I have a link that takes you to sample data - here it is again (http://pastebin.com/DyUnteN8) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pandas you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_table("toplot.txt", sep="\t")
#make D index (automatically puts it on the x axis)
dataset.set_index("D", inplace=True)
#plotting R vs. D
dataset.R.plot()
#plotting F vs. D
dataset.F.plot()
```

`dataset` is a `DataFrame` object and `DataFrame.plot` is just a wrapper around the matplotlib function to plot the series.

I'm not clear on how you are wanting to plot it, but it sound like you'll need to select some values of a column. This would be:

```
# get where F == 1000
maskF = dataset.F == 1000
# get the values where F == 1000
rows = dataset[maskF]
# get the values where A12 is in column E
rows = rows[rows.E == "A12"]
#remove the we don't want to see
del rows["E"]
del rows["F"]
#Plot the result
rows.plot(xlim=(0,None), ylim=(-1,2))
```

Comment: thanks for the sample code - I will work on it and let you know if I can get anything out of it (already had 2 exceptions - se_index give me duplicate errors, and ylim is not defined..) anyway - I will post updates. Thanks

Comment: the set_index was just for convenience. you can take it out and do `plot(x="D")` instead.

Comment: seems to be getting some meaningful plots!!! I will work on it, and come back for more questions on finetuning - thanks!

Comment: @Dimitris If this answer fully addressed _the question you asked_, you should accept the answer, and open a new question for the follow ons.  It helps keep the site tidy with 1 question per thread.

Comment: @tcaswell yes, I plan to do this after I am sure that the answer works - now I think I am in the right track - my slow updates are due to my inexperience and also lack of time - but will update to show solved if it indeed works

Comment: @Dimitris no worries, just (I hope) a gentle nudge to keep extensive follow up questions out of the comments

Comment: This worked great, and actually I start to like pandas....due to my inadequacy I had to add one more step, convert everything to numpy array, and then better manipulate the graphs - I know it is not the most efficient way, but for me it is having a steam engine after horsebackriding (using a spreadsheet to do the same)